# How to run React Boilerplate with forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, forever, react-boilerplate

I'm going to run [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) application forever in the server.
I found [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) and I'm not sure how I pass parameters to forever. The command to run server is like following:

`PORT=80 npm run start:production`

Seems like `forever start PORT=80 npm run start:production` doesn't help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing is that `PORT=80` part is setting the env variable, this kind of command should be in front of other commands. The other thing is that to run npm scripts with forever, you need to use different syntax, so `PORT=80 forever start -c "npm run start:production" /path/to/app/dir/`.

If you're running forever form the project folder, the path should be ./

Answer (score 5):

Or you can run a react application with **pm2** or with **nohup**

1) install pm2 globally

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

2) navigate to the project folder and execute, space is required after --

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

3) to see running instances

```
pm2 ps
```

4) to see the other options

```
pm2 --help
```

**To run with nohup**

1) navigate to the project folder

```
nohup bash -c 'npm start' &
```

Answer (score 0):

pm2 is superb production process manager for Node. In addition to starting and daemonizing any application, it has a built in load balancer.

Install pm2:

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

To add start and add deamon to your app, navigate to the app folder and:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

To make pm2 autoboot on server restart:

```
$ pm2 startup
```

Then copy and paste the code generated.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need:

1. Install forever using`npm install -g forever`
2. Run the forever command `PORT=<YOUR PORT> forever start -c "<command>" ./`

Your command can be for example `npm start` and `npm run dev`.

Use `./` only if you are in the project folder.

Port means your port number, usually `80` or `443`.