# Connect Route53 registered domain to amazon ec2 service

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have registered a domain on Route53, I have a react app running on port 3000 on amazon ec2 instance. To access the website I go to ipv4-address:3000. How to connect that registered domain to this ec2 instance. I have tried many ways by watching tutorial but failed.

Also how can I remove the port 3000 so that I can go see webpage with only example.com.

I am running react with pm2 and node js with forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Route53 to redirect traffic on ports 80 or 443 to port 3000. Think of a DNS record as a simple 'translation service' that takes a URL as input and 'translates' it to an IP address.
To achieve the redirection, you should use an Application Load Balancer by creating a listener on port 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS) that will redirect the traffic to your EC2 instance on port 3000.
You can find more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-listener.html) on the official docs regarding the creation of an HTTP listener.

Comment: You can also listen on port 80 instead of 3000. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103568/how-to-run-react-boilerplate-with-forever)  is addressing the question how to configure forever.